# xdebug.trace_format option not works

Tags: php, xdebug

I trying to make a human readable log file from xdebug without success.

When I open the log file, I see something like this:

```
version: 1
creator: xdebug 2.2.7
cmd: D:\Apache\htdocs\partcollect\index.php
part: 1
positions: line

events: Time

fl=php:internal
fn=php::define
11 0

fl=php:internal
fn=php::set_time_limit
13 0
```

and more...

I want to see the memory usage, and I found a script, what can read the human readable format log file, but if i change the `xdebug.trace_format = 2` or to any of the given options (0,1,2) nothing changes.

Of course, when I change this number, I restart the webserver.

Here is my xdebug section of my `php.ini` file.

```
zend_extension = D:\PHP\ext\php_xdebug-2.2.7-5.6-vc11-x86_64.dll
xdebug.remote_enable=1
xdebug.remote_host=127.0.0.1
xdebug.remote_autostart=0
xdebug.remote_connect_back=1
xdebug.idekey=netbeans-xdebug

xdebug.remote_port=9000
xdebug.remote_handler=dbgp
xdebug.overload_var_dump = 1;
xdebug.cli_color = 2
xdebug.show_exception_trace=1
xdebug.auto_trace=1
xdebug.var_display_max_children = -1
xdebug.var_display_max_data = -1
xdebug.var_display_max_depth = -1

;PROFILER 
xdebug.profiler_enable = 1
xdebug.profiler_output_name = callgrind.xdebug.out.%t
xdebug.profiler_output_dir = D:/PHP/xdebug-profiler/
xdebug.profiler_enable_trigger = 1
xdebug.show_mem_delta = 1
xdebug.trace_format = 0
```

What do I miss?